# How do I extract multiple pieces of information using a regex?

Tags: regex

I need to extract multiple pieces of information from a returned collection of strings. The strings consist of a number of "fields", for example:

```
{container="node-exporter", device="/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv", endpoint="http-metrics", fstype="ext4", instance="172.20.32.10:9100", job="node-exporter", mountpoint="/", namespace="prometheus", pod="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-xvz7v", service="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter"}
{container="node-exporter", device="/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv", endpoint="http-metrics", fstype="ext4", instance="172.20.32.11:9100", job="node-exporter", mountpoint="/", namespace="prometheus", pod="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-w8cqq", service="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter"}
{container="node-exporter", device="/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv", endpoint="http-metrics", fstype="ext4", instance="172.20.32.12:9100", job="node-exporter", mountpoint="/", namespace="prometheus", pod="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-4wfhq", service="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter"}
{container="node-exporter", device="/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv", endpoint="http-metrics", fstype="ext4", instance="172.20.32.13:9100", job="node-exporter", mountpoint="/", namespace="prometheus", pod="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-zfskj", service="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter"}
{container="node-exporter", device="/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv", endpoint="http-metrics", fstype="ext4", instance="172.20.32.15:9100", job="node-exporter", mountpoint="/", namespace="prometheus", pod="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-cllnv", service="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter"}
```

In this case, I want to extract the label and value of the `fstype`, `instance` and `mountpoint` fields. So for the example provided, I'd end up with something like the following:

```
fstype="ext4" instance="172.20.32.10:9100" mountpoint="/"
fstype="ext4" instance="172.20.32.11:9100" mountpoint="/"
fstype="ext4" instance="172.20.32.12:9100" mountpoint="/"
fstype="ext4" instance="172.20.32.13:9100" mountpoint="/"
fstype="ext4" instance="172.20.32.15:9100" mountpoint="/"
```

Can this be done with a regular expression? I've used REs for a long time, but never anything this complex. If the answer to that question is yes, how do I do it?

Comment: It's just not the best target for regex, though one should definitely exist. Why not regex-replace `="(?!,)` (or even without regex `="`, if you are sure that your values never end with `=`) with `:"` and simply load resulting JSON?

Comment: Yes, I would not go with a regex here. You can strip each line out of its starting and ending { }s, then split each line by ",", then by "=". Which programming language are you using ?

Comment: Well, that's the second part and I'm not even sure if that's an option (still researching that). I'm trying to use this in the Grafana metrics viewing application. The sample data I provided is what's being displayed in a chart legend. It needs to be pared down to only the fields that people would care about.

Comment: As per my prior comment, I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: I have no grafana knowledge, but I would search for grafana plugins that allow you to manipulate data, and then you would do what I suggested above, in whiever script/programming language would be available.

Comment: Why is it that everyone who has answered, has been downvoted? Are they really that bad suggestions? C'mon.

Answer (score -2):

This can easily be done with groups and string replace. See [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/NQ62NO/1):

```
.*(fstype="[^"]*").*?(instance="[^"]*").*?(mountpoint="[^"]*").*
```

with this replacement:

```
$1 $2 $3
```

**Explanation:**
We create three groups that match the keys for which you want to have the values. E.g. group 1: `(fstype="[^"]*")`. The groups can then be referred to by $1 - $n. In order for the resulting string to only contain the groups, we need to make the regex match the whole string. Thus the regex starts and ends with `.*`. Further explanations:

- `.*` - matches 0 to infinity non line-breaking character
- `.*?` - same as above with the difference that it matches 'lazy'. Meaning the regex tries to create the smallest possible match.
- `[^"]*` - matches 0 to infinity characters, that are not `"`.
- `(...)` - creates a group with the content resulting from the regex defined inside of the group.

**Small example with javascript:**

```js
let input = `
{container="node-exporter", device="/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv", endpoint="http-metrics", fstype="ext4", instance="172.20.32.10:9100", job="node-exporter", mountpoint="/", namespace="prometheus", pod="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-xvz7v", service="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter"}
{container="node-exporter", device="/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv", endpoint="http-metrics", fstype="ext4", instance="172.20.32.11:9100", job="node-exporter", mountpoint="/", namespace="prometheus", pod="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-w8cqq", service="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter"}
{container="node-exporter", device="/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv", endpoint="http-metrics", fstype="ext4", instance="172.20.32.12:9100", job="node-exporter", mountpoint="/", namespace="prometheus", pod="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-4wfhq", service="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter"}
{container="node-exporter", device="/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv", endpoint="http-metrics", fstype="ext4", instance="172.20.32.13:9100", job="node-exporter", mountpoint="/", namespace="prometheus", pod="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-zfskj", service="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter"}
{container="node-exporter", device="/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv", endpoint="http-metrics", fstype="ext4", instance="172.20.32.15:9100", job="node-exporter", mountpoint="/", namespace="prometheus", pod="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-cllnv", service="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter"}
`;

const regex = /.*(fstype="[^"]*").*?(instance="[^"]*").*?(mountpoint="[^"]*").*/g;

const newStr = input.replaceAll(regex, "$1 $2 $3");
console.log(newStr);
```

Notes:

- you need to use the `replaceAll(...)` function. Otherwise, only the first match of the regex will be replaced. That leads to a minor adaptation of the regex. It needs the 'global' flag, which gets activated in the example by the `g` at the end of the regex.

### Remarks

Depending on the complete task you need to accomplish it might be more reasonable to use a library for the data structure you're given. From your example I suspect it to be [JSON5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json5). Depending on which programming language you're using, there are many approaches with different libraries. If you are just using an editor (like VS Code or Notepad++) you can just use the regex I provided in the integrated search function.

Answer (score -2):

> *"Can this be done with a regular expression?"*

Yes, it's called a *["capture"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended)*.

> *"If the answer to that question is yes, how do I do it?"*

There are many websites that allow for regular-expression pattern evaluation, and capture.

A popular website used by many *Stack Overflow* users is, *[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)*.

You can use the following pattern.

```
(fstype|instance|mountpoint)=.(.+?)\"
```

Output

```
fstype, ext4
instance, 172.20.32.10:9100
mountpoint, /
fstype, ext4
instance, 172.20.32.11:9100
mountpoint, /
fstype, ext4
instance, 172.20.32.12:9100
mountpoint, /
fstype, ext4
instance, 172.20.32.13:9100
mountpoint, /
fstype, ext4
instance, 172.20.32.15:9100
mountpoint, /
```

Answer (score -7):

To extract the desired fields from the collection of strings using regular expressions, you can follow these steps:

Construct the regular expression pattern: The pattern should match the desired fields and capture their values. Based on your example, the pattern can be constructed as follows:
fstype="([^"]+)" instance="([^"]+)" mountpoint="([^"]+)"

Here, ([^"]+) captures any non-quote characters and assigns them to the respective groups.

Compile and apply the regular expression: Use a regular expression library in your programming language of choice (e.g., Python's re module) to compile the pattern and apply it to each string in the collection.

Iterate over the collection and extract the fields: For each string, apply the regular expression pattern and retrieve the captured groups. Here's an example in Python:
import re

strings = [
'{container="node-exporter", device="/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv", endpoint="http-metrics", fstype="ext4", instance="172.20.32.10:9100", job="node-exporter", mountpoint="/", namespace="prometheus", pod="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-xvz7v", service="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter"}',
# Add the remaining strings here
]

pattern = r'fstype="([^"]+)" instance="([^"]+)" mountpoint="([^"]+)"'

for string in strings:
matches = re.findall(pattern, string)
if matches:
for match in matches:
fstype, instance, mountpoint = match
print(f"fstype="{fstype}" instance="{instance}" mountpoint="{mountpoint}"")

This code will iterate over each string, apply the regular expression pattern, and extract the desired fields. It will then print the extracted fields in the desired format.

Keep in mind that regular expressions can be powerful but may not be the best choice for all parsing tasks. If the structure of your strings varies significantly or becomes more complex, you may need to consider alternative parsing techniques or libraries that provide more advanced pattern matching and extraction capabilities.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).  If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.